# problema de código en java , cliente-servidor

Tags: java, derby

tengo un problema con un codigo , espero me puedan ayudar.
Estoy haciendo una base de datos enbebida y me sale erro al momento de registrar datos

```
  String tabla="create table Usuarios(Id int PRIMARY KEY,Nombre Varchar(50),Apellidos Varchar(50),Usuario Varchar(10),Clave Varchar(10))";
            PreparedStatement ps=con.prepareStatement(tabla);
            ps.execute();
            ps.close();
```

Esto es el botón registro:

```
    private void btnuserActionPerformed(java.awt.event.ActionEvent evt) {                                        
    // TODO add your handling code here:
            cone2 = conex.CargarBD();
    if(cone2!=null){
        
        try {
        Statement orden = cone2.createStatement ();
        String crear ="Insert Into Usuarios(Id,Nombre, Apellidos,Usuarios,clave) VALUES("
                +" "+txtid.getText()+",'"+txtnombre.getText()+"','"+txtapellido.getText()+"',"
                +" '"+txtuser.getText()+"',"+txtclave.getText()+"')";
        orden.executeUpdate(crear);
        System.out.println("Registro creado");
    }catch(SQLException ex){
            System.out.println("ERROR: "+ex);
    }
    }

}
```

Y este es mi error:

[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

Se supone que mi base de datos esta creada en mi carpeta :
[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

Comment: Y tu base de datos, tiene esa tabla?

Comment: En el primer codigo que puse, lo estoy creando supuestamente

Comment: supuestamente es algo que nosotros no podemos probar. Te fijaste que la base tenga esa tabla? te fijaste si estas pegandole a la misma base donde creas eso? la pregunta es clara, pero hay un monton de cosas que no podemos saber...